# Issue while using 2 NSTimers

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

I am working on an iOS app which provides/makes calls from app. We can make two calls one after another. First time we are making 1st call. Once call get established, the NSTimer should be fired and it would show the duration of the call.

For this I am doing following for timer

```
self.switchTimer1 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                 target:self
                                 selector:@selector(setTimerLabel1:)
                                 userInfo:nil
                                 repeats:YES];

[self.switchTimer1 fire];
```

after establishing this first call, user can make second call.

Once second call gets established, it would fire second timer.

```
if (hasSecondCall)
{

    self.switchTimer2 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                     target:self
                                     selector:@selector(setTimerLabel2:)
                                     userInfo:nil
                                     repeats:YES];

    timeSec=0;

    timeMin=0;

    [self.switchTimer2 fire];

}
```

It's working fine while making first time of both calls.

Suppose if I ended 2nd call and again I made call, that time 2nd timer before establishing the call the timer automatically calling and once call established, the timer incrementing value very fast like double values showing.  Like, 2,4, 6, etc.

For secondtimer after firing method following

```
- (void)setTimerLabel2:(NSTimer *)timer {

    timeSec=timeSec+1;

    NSLog(@"timeSec+1 %d",timeSec+1);

    if (timeSec == 60)
    {
        timeSec = 0;
        timeMin=timeMin+1;
    }

    NSString* timeNow = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", timeMin, timeSec];

    [_switchCallLCD setStatus:timeNow labelNumber:2];
}
```

While disconnecting call we calling following

```
- (void)endingCallWithId:(UInt32)call_id {

    if (hasSecondCall&& call_id==_current_call) {

        if (self.switchTimer2) {

            //NSLog(@"self.predictNumber %@",self.predictNumber);
            self.predictNumber=self.predictNumber2;
            [_lcd setText:self.predictNumber];

            [self.switchTimer2 invalidate];
            self.switchTimer2 = nil;
            [self.switchTimer2 release];
            [_switchCallLCD setStatus:NSLocalizedString(@"call ended",nil) labelNumber:2];

            timeSec = 0;
            timeMin = 0;
        }
```

I have searched so many forums regarding this issue, but I couldn't figure out solution. I heard, if we use multiple timers there is some issue like this.

Comment: What are `_current_call `, `timeSec` and `timeMin`, instance variables? Generally we use properties for ivars. Where is `endingCallWithId` called? It seems you are not using ARC (`[self.switchTimer2 release]`), that is not a good idea.

Comment: my app has some files arc and some of non-arc , but this file is non arc //In Header i declared these, eventhough i released them in dealloc method, nothing changes in timer status
int timeSec = 0;
int timeMin = 0;

Comment: once call get disconnected we are calling endingCallWithId method and thanks for your quick response @Zaph

Answer (score 0):

You likely still have the previous instance of the timer(s) running. When you make a second set of calls you then have 2 instances of switchTimer1 running and 2 instances of switchTimer2 running.

As soon as you end a call, you need to invalidate the timer:

```
[self.switchTimer1 invalidate];
```

and then set it to nil for good measure:

```
self.switchTimer1 = nil;
```

Comment: once i disconnected the 2nd call, there is still running the first call @Duncan c, after that ended the 2nd call, i am making again another call, that time i am facing this issue.

Comment: I see you posted code that shows you invalidating the 2nd timer. What about code to invalidate the first timer? If you want help figuring out your problems, you have to post all the relevant code.

Comment: I dint posted that code due to increasing more code here. I am also doing that first timer invalidating after call being get disconnected. but its working good. @Duncan c

Comment: The devil is in the details. You either need to post the code that's not working, or debug it yourself. (More than likely you're going to have to debug it yourself, since telling what's going on in a running app from a forum post is quite hard.)  I suggest adding log statements in the code that creates the timers, in the code that invalidates the timers, and in the methods that the timers call. Then you can see what's really happening.